# Two entities without collections

Tags: symfony

I have following issue. One entity with name "user" have an many to many relationship to entity "address". I would like to create a form "UserType". In this form i will show exactly to address entities. One address for privat address informations and one address for business adress informations.

I realized this with collection, i can add and remove many adress collections.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

But how can i exactly show two address entity on creating or editing a user without collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to it.  One is to add get/set privateAddress and businessAddress methods to you user entity then make sure you initialize the collections.  Something like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->addAddress(new Address('Private'));
$user->addAddress(new Address('Business'));

$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($user);
$builder
    ->add('privateAddress',  new AddressFormType())
    ->add('businessAddress', new AddressFormType())
;
```

I often use a second approach when creating an object with multiple children.  In this approach, you feed the form multiple independent objects in an array and then stitch things together after the form is posted.

```
$data = array(
    'user' => new User(),
    'privateAddress'  => new Address('Private'),
    'businessAddress' => new Address('Business'),
);
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data);
$builder
    ->add('user', new UserFormType())
    ->add('privateAddress',  new AddressFormType())
    ->add('businessAddress', new AddressFormType())
;
...
if ($form->isValid())
    // Stitch your object together then persist
```

Either method works.  The second one is a bit more flexible and avoids the need to add additional methods to the user object.  Of course, you will probably want those methods anyways.